# how to make a box reach the edge of a bigger box

Tags: javascript, html

javascript beginner here! so i'm trying to do a box(that is inside a larger box) move from the top to the edge of the box. Here's the code:

```js
var boxcont = document.getElementById("boxcont");
var boxbtn = document.getElementById("boxbtn");

boxbtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var loc = 0;
  var timebox = setInterval(boxmove, 5);
  function boxmove() {
    if (loc == 320) {
      clearInterval(timebox);
    } else {
      loc++;
      boxcont.style.top = loc + "px";
      boxcont.style.left = loc + "px";
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#movebox {
  width: 300px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: grey;
}
#boxcont {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: indianred;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="movebox">
    <div id="boxcont"></div>
</div>
<button id="boxbtn">Move the box</button>
```

The problem is that the small box doesn't exactly ends up at the edge, it goes more to the right. I tried doing

```
boxcont.style.left = (loc - 0.5) + "px";
```

but doesn't work. pretty sure the solution is simple but as a newbie here it's confusing me :p. Oh and i also tried doing ++ to the 0.5 and Number(0.5) so it reads it as a decimal but still doesn't work!

Comment: A little different than what you are doing, but you could do this with a css class: https://jsfiddle.net/fc3gmar5/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the big gray box is not set to the correct height and width that corresponds with the small red box's movement. You have it going down 1 and to the right 1 every 5 however, your actually going across a rectangle, not a square. set your width and height the same for the gray box and slightly adjust the stopping point to a little bit less.

```js
           
                var boxcont = document.getElementById("boxcont");
                var boxbtn = document.getElementById("boxbtn");

                boxbtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
                var loc = 0;
                var timebox = setInterval(boxmove, 5); // every five milliseconds
                function boxmove() {
                    if (loc == 290) {
                    clearInterval(timebox);
                    } else {
                    loc++;
                    boxcont.style.top = loc + "px";
                    boxcont.style.left = loc + "px";
                    }
                }
                });
```

```css
                
                #movebox {
                    width: 300px;
                    height: 350px;
                    background-color: grey;
                }
                #boxcont {
                    width: 30px;
                    height: 30px;
                    background-color: indianred;
                    position: relative;
                }
```

```html
                <div id="movebox" style = "height: 320px; width: 320px">
                    <div id="boxcont" ></div>
                </div>
                <button id="boxbtn">Move the box</button>
```

Comment: i know but what if i want the gray box be more in width but still make the red box reach it's edge. Problem solved by another user but thank you appreciate it :)

Comment: ok, i thought you wanted it to go from corner to corner. No problem!

Answer (score 0):

```
if (loc == 270) {
```

instead of

```
if (loc == 320) {
```

Gets you there.

300px is the width of the containing `div` and the moving `div` is 30px wide so 300-30=270px

```js
var boxcont = document.getElementById("boxcont");
var boxbtn = document.getElementById("boxbtn");

boxbtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var loc = 0;
  var timebox = setInterval(boxmove, 5);
  function boxmove() {
    if (loc == 270) {
      clearInterval(timebox);
    } else {
      loc++;
      boxcont.style.top = loc + "px";
      boxcont.style.left = loc + "px";
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#movebox {
  width: 300px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: grey;
}
#boxcont {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: indianred;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="movebox">
    <div id="boxcont"></div>
</div>
<button id="boxbtn">Move the box</button>
```